# Moving Redmine from Azure to other server

Tags: azure, redmine

I have a running instance of `Redmine` at `Azure`. I created that as `VM` at Azure. It has Redmine as pre-configured, ready-to-run. It is currently being used by a team for project management. But I want to move that `Redmine` instance to another server, along with data. I couldn't figure out, how to properly do that. I looked for the solution and found [THIS post](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Migrate_Redmine_to_a_new_server_to_a_new_Redmine_version), explaining how to migrate your Redmine. But it is not understandable, and I'm not sure if it is even applicable in my case *(azure redmine)*. Besides this, I am afraid if I mess with configuration, and it stops working, as it happened once.

I have to leave current azure account, so I have two options:

- Move existing redmine to new Azure server.
- Move existing redmine to new other server. *(preffered)*

Can somebody please provide me some guidelines/steps in order to accomplish my task? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic. That said: Your question is unclear: Are you trying to move to another VM in Azure? Moving it to a VM outside of Azure? Moving it to a computer in your data center?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, with respect, i disagree with both of your points, **but I need evidence, supporting both of your points**. 
- Firstly, if you see two bullets, the simply explains my question, hence question is not unclear, UNLESS you dont have knowledge about Redmines, Azure etc.
- Secondly, I am asking for the solution here at SO, how can you rank my question as off-topic? Please keep the SO a platform of it purpose, but not ego, based on knowledge.

Comment: You don't have to agree with me at all. But ego has zero to do with it: Your question is off-topic. Not sure what counts as evidence. Perhaps the StackOverflow help about [on topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Specifically called out: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* And voting to close your question is in line with your desire to "keep SO a platform of its purpose."

Comment: @DavidMakogon. Thank you, I removed the word `tutorial` from the question, which you thought had changed the meaning of it. **BUT** the evidence/proof for your first point is still required. Where do you have find my question totally unclear? Let's say it is unclear *(for the sake of argument)*, viewer still has the right to ask for the clearification, instead of cheap downvoting and closing it, so that no other (with concerned knowledge may see it). Now I believe, John Galloway had correct reason to quit SO. Some people are taking it other direction with ego

Answer (score 3):

The folks at Plano are doing this for you: https://plan.io/data-import-and-migration/

Their basically a Redmine hoster. You have to become a customer with them but prices seem fair even compared with azure and you get all the management with it.

Comment: Thank you Danny. Is it possible to simply backup my current redmine, and restore it to other (my own) server? The reason is, I wan't to avoid going for cloud services, and prefer hosting it personally at linux/windows server.